# $F=\{ f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}| f$ is an entire function,$ |f'(z)| \leq |f(z)|$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

> Consider $F=\{ f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}| f$ is an entire function,$ |f'(z)| \leq |f(z)|$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}\}.$
>
> Then which of the following is true?
>
> 1) $F$ is a finite set.
>
> 2) $F$ is an infinite set.
>
> 3) $F=\{ \beta e^{\alpha z}: \beta \in \mathbb{C}, \alpha \in \mathbb{C}\}$
>
> 4) $F=\{ \beta e^{\alpha z}: \beta \in \mathbb{C}, |\alpha| \leq 1\}$

1) is false and 2) is true as functions in option 4) satisfy above propetry.

Also 3) is false as for $\alpha=2 $ and $\beta =1$ the property does not hold true.

Is 4) true?

Comment: What do you have to check to verify or refute option 4?

Comment: I have to check if it is true

Comment: What *specific* fact must you check?

Comment: If there is any non exponential function with that property

Comment: Hint: consider $|f'(z)|/|f(z)|$ and apply Liouville's theorem.

Comment: Prehint to that of @rubikscube09: if $f$ is not identically zero, can $f$ have a zero?

Comment: yes.....I got it ...thank you @rubikscube09 and peter a g